# Finding elements in Flask + Jinja

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, queryselector

I am trying to create an flask app that uses Jinja templating. I have a navbar that contains links with the class name 'nav-link'. They are in [base.html](https://github.com/CODEMASTER2321/Finding-elements-in-Flask-Jinja/blob/main/base.html). I dynamically create [index.html](https://github.com/CODEMASTER2321/Finding-elements-in-Flask-Jinja/blob/main/index.html). Later I try to acess the links in `script.js`:

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
```

I log the `navLinks` into the console and this is what I get:

[image: NodeList]

Is there a way to get dynamically created elements? A way to add event listenrs onto them? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you showing us a variable called `NodeList`?  What connection does that have, if any, to `navLinks`?

Comment: When, exactly, does the `document.querySelectorAll` script run?  Does it run when the page loads, or does it run later?  Can you show us the exact context of when that function is executed?

Comment: The nodelist is what shows up in the terminal when I log the navLinks into the console. I add a "DomContentLoaded" event listener onto the window, and the first line after that is the `document.querySelectorAll`